# Checking if the intersection of two cyclic $p$-adic extensions with certain properties is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $L$ and $L'$ be finite extensions of $K = \mathbb{Q}_p$. Also, let $n = [L:K]$ and $e = e(L/K)$.
Furthermore, we assume the following properties:

- $L$ and $L'$ are both cyclic over $K$,
- $L'/K$ is totally ramified of degree $e$,
- $LL'/L'$ is unramified of degree $n$.

> **Question** Is it true that $L \cap L' = K$?

I think this is true but I cannot prove why. I also tried to consider the case where $n$ is a prime power but it did not work out. All I know is that $L \cap L'/K$ as both $L$ and $L'$ contain $K$.

Could someone please help me to answer my question? Thank you again!

Comment: The fact that the degree of $L/K$ lifts over $L'$ without falling is enough to conclude that the intersection is $K$.

Comment: seconded, this is not related to $p$-adic fields or ramification -- if $L \cap L'$ contained $K$ with index greater than one, then $LL'$ could not be degree $n$ over $L'$ (a minimal polynomial for $L$ over $L \cap L'$ would serve as a minimal polynomial for $LL'$ over $L'$).

Comment: @hunter: I understand the gist of the argumentation now. Could you please explain why a minimal polynomial for $L$ over $L \cap L'$ would serve as a minimal polynomial for $LL'$ over $L'$? Does it has something to do with Galois extensions being generated by primitive elements?